# Excel how to find the closest date to another date, matched for the same ID number in two sets of data?

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets, each sheet has a list of ID numbers and multiple dates associated with these ID numbers. I want to find the closest date on the second sheet of data to the date on first sheet, matched to the same ID. For example, for ID 1234 01/24/2012 on sheet one, I want to be able to know the closest date for ID 1234 to that date on sheet 2.

Comment: VBA is a good candidate for this. Care to share anything you have attempted (formulas, tables, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula:

```
{=INDEX($G$1:$G$10,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B1-$G$1:$G$10*(A1=$F$1:$F$10))),ABS(B1-$G$1:$G$10*(A1=$F$1:$F$10)),0))}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the Dynamic Array formula available in Office 365:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(G1:G11,F1:F11=A1),@SORT(ABS(B1-FILTER(G1:G11,F1:F11=A1)))=ABS(B1-FILTER(G1:G11,F1:F11=A1)))
```

[image]